# Why Syntax error appears on the following if condition

Tags: java

Hi I have a following if condition in java

```
if ((i%3)==0)
    do some work
else if ((i%3 || i%5)==0)----syntax error appears on this line
    do some work
```

And it is showing me following syntax error...
Multiple markers at this line
    - The operator || is undefined for the argument 
     type(s) int, int
    - Syntax error on token "OR", . expected
    - i cannot be resolved or is not a field

can any one please tell me how can i fix this one ??

Comment: Think about it this way: What does `(i%3 || i%5)` mean?

Comment: shot-in-the-dark: are you trying to do [this](http://projecteuler.net/problem=1) problem?

Comment: Try reading some basic tutorials on Java... If statements don't work like that.

Comment: yeah dennis the same one...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the comparison with every part of the condition. In this case your `else if` should look like this

```
else if (i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't specify multiple conditions like that.  The `||` operator operates on `boolean` values only; it can't operate on numbers the way you would like them to operate.  You must specify each condition individually:

```
else if ((i%3 == 0) || (i%5 == 0))
```

In English, we would say "`i` is a multiple of 3 or 5" and we would know what you mean.  It doesn't work that way in Java.  You must be more explicit.  The required Java code is equivalent to "`i` is a multiple of 3 or `i` is a multiple of 5".

Answer (score 0):

the `||` operator can only be used on bool types. `i%3` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Logical operator can only applied to boolean conditions. you are applying OR condition for two integers. If your i is 10, then i%3 = 1 and i%5 = 0. So then you are evaluating (1 || 0). If you really want to do that then you should use bitwise operator (|). Otherwise, use parenthesis which you already used in the first if part. so it will be either

```
else if((i%3 == 0) || (i%5 == 0))

or

else if((i%3 | i%5) == 0)
```

Thanks